# Possible causes slow order by on sql server statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sqlperformance

I have the next query which returns 1550 rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM V_InventoryMovements -- 2 seconds
ORDER BY V_InventoryMovements.TransDate -- 23 seconds
```

It takes about 2 seconds to return the results.
But when I include the ORDER BY clause, then it takes about 23 seconds.
It is a BIG change just for adding an ORDER BY.

I would like to know what is happening, and a way to improve the query with the ORDER BY. To quit the ORDER BY should not be the solution.

Here a bit of information, please let me know if you need more info.

V_InventoryMovements

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_InventoryMovements]
AS
SELECT some_fields
FROM FinTime
RIGHT OUTER JOIN V_Outbound ON FinTime.StdDate = dbo.TruncateDate(V_Outbound.TransDate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReasonCode_Grouping ON dbo.V_Outbound.ReasonCode = dbo.ReasonCode_Grouping.ReasonCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON V_Outbound.ITEM = Items.Item
LEFT OUTER JOIN FinTime ON V_Outbound.EventDay = FinTime.StdDate
```

V_Outbound

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Outbound]
AS
SELECT V_Outbound_WMS.*
FROM V_Outbound_WMS
UNION
SELECT V_Transactions_Calc.*
FROM V_Transactions_Calc
```

V_OutBound_WMS

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_OutBound_WMS]
AS
SELECT some_fields
FROM Transaction_Log
INNER JOIN MFL_StartDate ON Transaction_Log.TransDate >= MFL_StartDate.StartDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rack ON Transaction_Log.CHARGE = Rack.CHARGE AND Transaction_Log.CHARGE_LFD = Rack.CHARGE_LFD
```

V_Transactions_Calc

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Transactions_Calc]
AS
SELECT some_fields
FROM Transactions_Calc
INNER JOIN MFL_StartDate ON dbo.Transactions_Calc.EventDay >= dbo.MFL_StartDate.StartDate
```

And here I will also share a part of the execution plan (the part where you can see the main cost). I don't know exactly how to read it and improve the query. Let me know if you need to see the rest of the execution plan. But all the other parts are 0% of Cost. The main Cost is in the: Nested Loops (Left Outer Join) Cost 95%.

Execution Plan With ORDER BY

[image]

Execution Plan Without ORDER BY

[image]

Comment: sidenote: are you selecting from a view inside another view ? Dont do that, this is very bad for performance

Comment: Upload your [actual execution plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. `ORDER BY` can be expensive depending on the particulars of the query and available indexes. I would guess here that the sort operator with the `ORDER BY` is on the ordered column whereas the sort without it is on a different column(s) for the merge join operator. Merge join is generally more efficient for a large number of rows but the `ORDER BY` might preclude use of merge join use and be very expensive overall.

Comment: As @GuidoG said nested views are bad for performance. They seem so logical but they are will cripple your system. See this from Grant Fritchey on the topic. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @Dan Guzman, nice link, I didn't know that tool ;-)

Comment: @Sean Lange, Thanks for the link also. Very interesting information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is that the optimizer is executing in a different order in an attempt to minimize the cost of the sorting, and doing a poor job. Its job is made very hard by the views within views within views, as GuidoG suggests. You might be able to convince it to execute differently by creating some additional index or statistics, but its going to be hard to advise on that remotely.

A possible workaround might be to select into a temp table, then apply the ordering afterwards:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM V_InventoryMovements; 

SELECT *
FROM #temp
ORDER BY TransDate
```

Comment: Or a common table expression.

Comment: @James Casey you got it. I know views inside views cannot be the best, but sometimes (many times) you need to do it, and not always it's a pain (like this case). In any case, your simple script creating the temp table is surprisingly fast. SELECT INTO TempTable + SELECT FROM TempTable it takes about 2 seconds. Awesome! (But not perfect... SQL Server needs this tricky steps to work faster? Uhm...)